# A simple $C_{0}$-semigroup question.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, semigroup-of-operators

Let $u:[0,t_{e}]\to\mathcal{D}(A)$ satisfy

$$\begin{cases}
\frac{du}{dt}=Au &  0\le t \le t_{e} \\ u(0)=x
\end{cases}$$

I want to prove that necessarily $u(t)=T(t)x$.

So it's clear to see that $T(0)x=x=u(0)$. And $\frac{d}{dt}T(t)x=AT(t)x=Au$, if $u(t)=T(t)x$.

How can I complete this proof? I assume, at least, by making the supposition that $u(t)\ne T(t)x$ and then looking for a proof by contradiction.

Comment: What's your definition of T(t)?

Comment: @NateEldredge For a Banach space $X$, and for each $t>0$, $T(t):X\to X$ is a bounded linear operator and $\{T(t)\}_{t\ge 0}$ is a $C_{0}$-semigroup with infinitesimal generator $A$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You proved that $T(t)x$ is a solution. So, it remains to show that the problem has only one solution.

Let $u$ and $v$ be two solutions. Notice that the function $w=u-v$ satisfies
$$\left\{\begin{align}
&\frac{dw}{dt}=Aw, &  0\le t \le t_{e} \\
&w(0)=0.
\end{align}\right.$$
Pick $s\in[0,t_e]$ and define $\phi:[0,s]\to X$ be setting $\phi(t)=T(t)w(s-t)$. Then,
$$\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}\phi(t)&=\frac{d}{dt}T(t)w(s-t)-T(t)\frac{d}{dt}w(s-t)\\
&=AT(t)w(s-t)-T(t)Aw(s-t)\\
&=T(t)Aw(s-t)-T(t)Aw(s-t)\\
&=0.
\end{align}$$

It follows that $\phi$ is constant, that is, $\phi(t_1)=\phi(t_2)$ for all $t_1,t_2\in[0,s]$. Taking $t_1=0$ and $t_2=s$, we obtain

$$u(s)-v(s)=w(s)=T(0)w(s-0)=\phi(0)=\phi(s)=T(s)w(s-s)=T(s)0=0.$$

Since $s$ is arbitrary, we conclude that $u=v$ on $[0,t_e]$.

**Remark:** This argument appears in many books in the proof of the following result: If $A:D(A)\subset X\to X$ is the infinitesimal generator of a $C_0$-semigroup $\{T(t)\}_{t\geq 0}$ on $X$, then, for each $U_0\in D(A)$, the abstract Cauchy problem $U_t=AU$, $U(0)=U_0$ has an unique classical solution. Moreover, this solution is given by $U(t)=T(t)U_0$. See, for example, [Goldstein's book](https://books.google.com.br/books/about/Semigroups_of_linear_and_nonlinear_opera.html?id=XfjuAAAAMAAJ&redir_esc=y) (page 83) and [Zheng's book](https://books.google.com.br/books/about/Nonlinear_Evolution_Equations.html?id=k2a18LVAXUYC&redir_esc=y) (page 34). In fact, as we can see in [Pazy's book](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=1YWmMAEACAAJ&dq=inauthor:%22Amnon+Pazy%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0CBwQ6AEwAGoVChMIp77q9MrRxwIVhxCQCh13KgQl) (page 105) , a similar argument can also be applied to prove uniqueness of classical solution for inhomogeneous Cauchy problems.

Comment: Since my proposed answer is a counterexample, I'm struggling to figure out the error in your answer.  I think you need to show rigorously that $\frac d{dt} \phi(t)$ exists.  (You also need to define in what space this derivative is calculated.)

Comment: I'm thinking about it even more.  How do you justify the product formula?  Things that work fine in finite dimensions don't necessarily follow in the infinite dimensional case.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith I don't have a explicit proof for this product rule, but I added some references in the post where it is applied (also, [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/639364/is-the-product-rule-true-in-a-banach-algebra) there is something similar). In fact, my answer is the classical argument that can be found in operator semigroups books. Since, probably, you know these books, I think that I'm missing something.

Comment: No, I am probably wrong!

Comment: So while I have written papers on semigroup theory, I have read very little of the literature!

Comment: @Pedro Isn't this proof essentially the same as if $S=\{S(t)\}_{t\ge 0}$ and $T=\{T(t)\}_{t\ge 0}$ both have infinitesimal generator $A$, then $S=T$?