# If $\exp(t(A + B)) = \exp(tA) \exp(tB)$ for all $t \geq 0$ then $A,B$ commute

Tags: matrices, analysis, exponential-function, semigroup-of-operators, matrix-exponential

Let $A,B$ be complex valued square matrices. If $\exp(t(A + B)) = \exp(tA) \exp(tB)$ for all $t \geq 0$ then $A,B$ commute.

[The converse](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/568450/m-n-in-bbb-r-n-times-n-show-that-emn-emen-given-mn-nm) of this statement can be an easy application of the Cauchy product rule and the binomial theorem.

[Note](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/349180/if-ea-and-eb-commute-do-a-and-b-commute) that this statement doesn't hold, if we restrict ourselves to $t = 1$.

So far I have been trying to use the fact, that $A$ and $B$ are infinitesimal generators to the semigroups $\{\exp(tA)\}$ and $\{\exp(tB)\}$ but I have had no success. Do you have any other hints?

---

Based on the idea of @Did, I came up with the following:

Series expansions give me:
$$
\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{t^n(A + B)^n}{n!} = I + tA + tB + \frac{t^2(AB + BA)}{2} + \sum_{n = 3}^\infty \frac{t^n(A + B)^n}{n!} 
$$
and
$$
\left(\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{t^n(A)^n}{n!} \right) \left(\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{t^n(B)^n}{n!} \right)
= I + tA + tB + \frac{t^2A^2}{2} +  t^2AB +  \frac{t^2B^2}{2} + \sum_{n = 3}^\infty t^n c_n,
$$
where 
$$
c_n := \sum_{k = 0}^n \frac{A^k B^{n - k}}{k! n!}.
$$

The comparison of both expansions gives
$$
\frac{t^2(AB + BA)}{2} + \sum_{n = 3}^\infty \frac{t^n(A + B)^n}{n!} 
= t^2AB + \sum_{n = 3}^\infty t^n c_n.
$$
Division by $t > 0$ yields:
$$
\frac{(AB + BA)}{2} + \sum_{n = 3}^\infty \frac{t^{n-2}(A + B)^n}{n!} 
= AB + \sum_{n = 3}^\infty t^{n-2} c_n.
$$
But I can't quite see, why the two sums $\sum_{n = 3}^\infty \dots$ should go to $0$ for $t \to 0$ yielding the desired equality
$$
\frac{(AB + BA)}{2}  
= AB .
$$

Comment: Expansions when $t\to0$ up to order $t^2$ show that $$\tfrac12(A+B)^2=AB+\tfrac12A^2+\tfrac12B^2$$ which proves that $AB+BA=2AB$, qed. (And the argument is already on the other page.)

Comment: @Did: This seems plausible, but I don't have a rigorous proof of this yet, see my updated post.

Comment: Because the matrix norms of $A$ and $B$ are finite hence one can bound the terms of the two series involved to show that they both converge for every $t$. As an example, use $$c_3=\frac16A^3+\frac12A^2B+\frac12AB^2+\frac16B^3$$ hence $$\|c_3\|\leqslant\frac16\|A\|^3+\frac12\|A\|^2\|B\|+\frac12\|A\|\|B\|^2+\frac16\|B\|^3$$

Comment: Another approach is to use the [BCH formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula)

Comment: What do you mean when you say "the two sums should go to $0$"?  Of course they shouldn't go to zero; $\exp(0) = I$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: I have updated my post. I am referring to the $\Sigma_{n = 3}^\infty \dots$ terms on both sides.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: I would need to prove that both sums $\sum_{n = 3}^\infty \dots$ converge uniformly so I can interchange the limit of the sum with the limit $t \to 0$ to prove my claim. Do you have a proof for this?

Comment: @el_tenedor sure, use the [Weierstrass $M$-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test).

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thanks. Majorizing with $$\sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{(A + B)^n}{n!}$$, i.e. setting $t=1$, gives uniform convergence on $[0,1]$ which should suffice in my case, right? (similarly with the other sum)

Comment: That's right${}{}$

Answer (score 5):

Let us write $T(t)=e^{t(A+B)}$ and $S(t)=e^{tA}e^{tB}$. Then, using (for both) the [product rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/639364/is-the-product-rule-true-in-a-banach-algebra) and (for $S(t)$) the fact that the generator commutes with the semigroup,

$$\frac{d}{dt}T(t)=(A+B)T(t),\quad \frac{d}{dt}S(t)=AS(t)+S(t)B$$
$$\frac{d^2}{dt^2}T(t)=(A+B)^2T(t),\quad \frac{d^2}{dt^2}S(t)=A^2S(t)+2AS(t)B+S(t)B^2\tag{1}$$

Since $T(t)=S(t)$ for all $t\geq 0$, we have
$$\frac{d^2}{dt^2}T(t)=\frac{d^2}{dt^2}S(t),\quad\forall\ t\geq 0$$
and thus, from $(1)$,
$$(AB+BA)S(t)+B^2S(t)=2AS(t)B+S(t)B^2,\quad\forall\ t\geq 0.$$
In particular, for $t=0$,
$$AB+BA=2AB$$
and the desired result follows.

**Remark:** This solution follows the hint in [Engel's book](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=q0YMCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA23&lpg=PA23&dq=%22compute+the+second+derivative+of+the+functions+appearing%22&source=bl&ots=2QVc8DbQ1C&sig=cBXLR28mLzzMRGnFyt_g-Q0jF5E&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiz8_7P5obQAhUFfZAKHREfB_oQ6AEIIjAB#v=onepage&q=%22compute%20the%20second%20derivative%20of%20the%20functions%20appearing%22&f=false), page 23.

Comment: @user1551 Thank you for the correction. I edited the post.